# How to go to previous cursor location in Processing

Tags: processing, processing-ide

Is there a way to go back to the previous location in the Processing IDE? I have a huge program and I have to search for a function using Ctrl+F right now, which I would just have been a minute ago. Other IDEs let you trace your path back. (atleast I know IntellijIDEA does)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, there isn't a history in the Processing editor.

You really shouldn't be using the Processing editor for huge programs anyway. If your program is really that huge, note that you can use [Processing as a Java library](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) and use a more advanced IDE.